# Model has slightly deformed areas when I animate it

Tags: animation, mesh

I have an issue that I've been trying to solve for the past few days, with no luck. I'm using a model for a project, yet when I animate the model, the geometry seems to flex and move. The model is grouped together, and it's viewed through a camera.

The model was imported, and I added/changed some textures. I then imported the model into my project, and parented it to an animated camera. I still get the issue even when the object has to relationship to any other objects.

I believe it could be the clipping size in the viewport, but I'm not sure. I feel it could also be a scene scale issue, as when I scale up the model, it seems to look better, with less deformed geometry, but then the model is far too large. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: As you can see, around the viewport the geometry isn't clean. It changes every frame, so it looks really strange. You can also see this happen on the all of the radar and screens.]

Comment: I can’t tell by the image what is being deformed. I can say that it has nothing to do with clip size. A low clip size will make shapes that are super far away just disappear.

Comment: If you look at the light gray areas around the window, and the radar in the middle, the circle. It is no longer a circle. It's a bit difficult to explain sorry

Comment: Hmm, yeah that is strange. Well, if it’s happening with animation, I would suspect some kind of modifier. Any modifiers in place?

Comment: There was a rigid body, but that has been removed. Nothing has changed

Comment: OK, well, just to make sure, this whole ship is one mesh object, right?

Comment: It is a group of different meshes. So yes, one single object.

Comment: How do you mean by group? A Blender Group is not a Blender Object, which is what I am talking about. If you are in object mode, can you select the entire ship with a single click?

Comment: Yes, I am able to select the entire ship with one click, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Hmm, and no modifiers. Ok, any vertex parents, or materials with something connected to Displacement? Any physics?

Comment: It's parented to a camera, but even without the parent the issue is still there. No physics applied as I can tell, all are disabled. The materials are not connected to Displacement. Materials are emission and Principled BSDF, thought I doubt that would be the issue here.

Comment: What I mean is that node materials have an optional output called “displacement“ that, if rendered in cycles, actually moves the mash about. This is really useful for creating planet textures. It’s right next to Surface and Volume on the output node.

Comment: Yep, none of the materials have that output. And I am rendering In Eevee

Comment: OK, well, the last idea I have is a vertex parenting set up, but I have no idea how to check for that. I have very little experience with vertex parenting. I think you’ve gotten to the end of what can be diagnosed without sharing your blend file, though I might be wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I have no Vertex Parenting set up on the model as far as I can tell. There is no Vertex group. The model is made up of many objects, which I selected all of them, then right clicked and selected the join option.

Comment: Is the model very small or very large? What GPU are you using? I’m starting to suspect precision errors.

Comment: It's original dimensions is from x,y,z: 6.26,,55.8,02. In my scene I have it as 1.12,1.17,1.43 The units are in M. In my scene, it looks blurry when scaled down, so I assume that could potentially be an issue. I am using MSI GeForce 2070 super as my GPU